# Is there a specific property to allow Telerik toolwindow to be docked as tab group

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm using a Telerik ToolWindow and I add to it a WinForms UserControl but when I do that and try to drag the toolwindow, dock hints only show some docking options that don't include the tab group docking.

```
Dim x = new CustomUserControl()
Dim toolWindow As New ToolWindow
With toolWindow
            .Tag = MapControl
            .CloseAction = closing
            .Controls.Add(MapControl)
            .DataBindings.Add(someMethod(MapControl))
End With
desktop.AddDocument(toolWindow)
```

CustomUserControl inherits UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to note that ToolWindow is a part of the RadDock control: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/dock/overview
It is a specific window that can be dragged and dropped within the RadDock control.

Please refer to the following help articles demonstrating how to setup a RadDock with a ToolWindow at run time:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/dock/object-model/creating-a-raddock-at-runtime
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/dock/object-model/creating-toolwindow-and-documentwindow-at-runtime

I hope this information helps.